# styles of text inside a span tag in h1 tag don't applied well

Tags: css

I'm trying to have something looks like the following image:

[image: logo example with the correct output]

I have an h1 tag for the blue text, and inside of it I will have a span tag for the pink text.

**HTML**

That is why my html looks like this:

```
<div className="header_container">
        <header>
          <h1>
            text
            <span>ti</span>
          </h1>
        </header> 
</div>
```

(I use react, so that's why 'className' is for)

**SCSS**

To acheive this kind of styling I've defined this in my scss file:

```
.header_container{
    position: relative;
    color: #181d3d; /*blue color*/
    h1{
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 3.75rem;
        line-height: 4.725rem;
        span {
            color: #ec6c83; /*pink color*/
        }
    }  
}
```

**What is the problem?**

For some reason this is the output I get in the browser:

[image: logo example with the wrong output]

It seems like because of the text inside the span tag starts with the same letter the h1 text ends with (the letter 't'), it is kind of ignoring the style for first 't' letter in the span tag.

For example I've tried to replace the first 't' letter inside the span tag to a 's' letter, and the results were satisfying: [image: logo example with 'si' instead of 'ti']

```
<div className="header_container">
        <header>
          <h1>
            text
            <span>si</span>
          </h1>
        </header> 
</div>
```

Or just adding a whitespace inside the span tag, and also getting satisfying results that assures me the styles implementations are good: [image: logo example with ' ti' in span]

```
<div className="header_container">
        <header>
          <h1>
            text
            <span> ti</span>
          </h1>
        </header> 
      </div>
</div>
```

Is this actually a bug or is it the fact that I'm doing something wrong?

All I expect is that the output of my code will result in this way as mentioned above: [image: logo exemple with the currect output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doubled `t` look extremely close this might be cause by font ligatures.
Try to apply to your `h1`

```css
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```